# how to deploy ruby on rails application in xampp in windows xp?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xampp

I'm very new to Ruby environment ..
I want to run my Ruby on rails Application in apache  in xampp on windows xp rather than WeBrick server which is in-built for ruby on rails...

I tried it by adding Virtual host in apache- http.conf file

When i run my application i'm able to see "Welcome Abroad"....

But when i click on "About your application’s environment" 
it was showing error like the following

```
Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404
localhost
9/9/2011 10:47:31 AM
Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8o PHP/5.3.4 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1
```

Comment: Any specific reason you want to run it on Apache instead of WebRick?

Comment: yes.. it's my client requirement

Comment: Ok. I was thinking it's for development not for production

Answer (score 0):

To deploy your app with apache you need to use phusion passenger http://www.modrails.com
There are plenty of how-to's around the web and the documentation is good enough to get the service running.

Answer (score -1):

This means your Ruby on Rails server is **NOT running**.
You need to run your server first.

I made a batch file, **start-server.bat** which contains

```
d:
cd "D:\Ruby\Web\rails1"
"C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin\ruby.exe" script\rails server
```

then check the PORT number of the server that is running,

[image: command prompt]

So since the port on the screenshot says 10524, you can run it on

```
http://localhost:10524/
```

Comment: This a very bad idea. It uses WEbrick not xampp at all.